# how to find out that windows 10 has just been updated?

Tags: windows-10, updates, auto-updates

We all know that on windows 10 not completely possible turn off updates.
How to find out that windows 10 has just been updated?
Maybe with powershell I can do this?

Comment: Hi Alex and welcome to Superuser. What is your final goal? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: [Powershell, How to get date of last Windows update install or at least checked for an update? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732541/powershell-how-to-get-date-of-last-windows-update-install-or-at-least-checked-f)

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot view which updates were recently installed within Windows Update and click on `View installed update history`?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke When Windows 10 updated (just now, recently) i need run powershell script.

Comment: @AlexF. But why does it need to run after an update? What is the whole problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke i have program whitch didnt work after windows updated, so I want update program after this.

Comment: Ok, where getting somewhere. Perhaps you can include that in your question? Feel free to mention which program this is. Does it have an auto update mode? Yes? Why can't you use it? What did you try up til now? Please, pretty please show a little bit of effort when posing the question.